# I Get This Error .NET Core "Unable to create an object of type 'Blog DbContext'. For..."

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Project Architecture:
https://www.hizliresim.com/fpmhevm

Startup.cs

```
using Application.Context;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Application;

public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<BlogDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("MainDB"),
                x => x.MigrationsAssembly("Application")));

        services.AddDbContext<BlogDbContext>();

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

BlogDbContext.cs

```
using Application.Models;

namespace Application.Context;

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class BlogDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }

    public BlogDbContext(DbContextOptions<BlogDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

How can I solve this error, I tried a lot, but I could not succeed.
I tried many times but the error persists, there is no problem with the connection string
I have never encountered such a problem in other projects.

Comment: In ASP.NET 6.0, Startup.cs class is removed and Program.cs class is the place where register the dependencies of the application and the middleware.  If you still want to write your middleware and dependencies in startup class?

Answer (score 0):

`Startup` classes were used in previous ASP.NET Core iterations with [the generic hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-7.0), now the default templates use "new" minimal hosting (what you have in the `Program.cs`), remove `Startup` class and move the db registration into the `Program.cs`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<BlogDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("MainDB"),
                x => x.MigrationsAssembly("Application")));
```